# Раскодировать страницу при парсинге Curl-ом

Tags: php, curl

При получении страницы происходит постоянный редирект, пока не передашь заголовок `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept-encoding: gzip, deflate'));`. Но когда заголовок добавил, то страница не обновляется, но выводиться каракулями.

```
$url = "https://m.vk.com/video-51109251_456239104";

$cookie_file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/VKCOOKIE";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept-encoding: gzip, deflate'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модули на сервере включены `gzip compression`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На странице был скрипт, который редиректит на другой адрес. Можно вырезать его регулярным выражением или с помощью библиотеки phpQuery.
В таком случае мы можем убрать строку `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept-encoding: gzip, deflate'));`

Answer (score 3):

Вы сказали удалённому серверу, что готовы принять `gzip`. Вам ответили `gzip`. А вот curl'у вы не сказали, что ожидается `gzip` и он, в лучших традициях unix-way ничего раскодировать не пытается, а передаёт вам всё в точности так, так ему ответил удалённый сервер.

Варианта действий есть два:

- получать заголовки ответа вместе с телом, по ним разбираться, как ответили и соответственно этому раскодировать данные.
- попросить этим заняться сам `curl`. Если внимательно почитать [обширнейший список опций](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), то можно найти опцию, которая сформирует корректный заголовок `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` и самостоятельно обработает ответ:

  ```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
  ```

Comment: Начинается бесконечный редирект. Буд-то на странице есть скрипт, которые редиректит.